# Не удачная адаптация table под телефон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Почему у меня на телефоне таблица не хочет отображаться как на компьютере? На компьютере Google Chrome, на телефоне FireFox, всё свежее.

CSS :

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
input[type="image"] {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/mytable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-new" role="navigation" >

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Меню</a>
        </div>
        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
    <div class="row" style="
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="
    width: 100%;
">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="images/star.png" name="имя"></td>
   </tr>
  </table> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Компьютер :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телефон :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для firefox необходимо так input[type="image"] {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} - https://jsfiddle.net/st6xssxL/

Comment: а как сделать чтобы css мог переключаться для каждого браузера по отдельности, чтобы этот сайт работал и в хроме и в firefox

Comment: зачем по отдельности? в данном случае пропишите что я выше написал будет работать и в chrome и firefox

Comment: @soledar10 ну на компьютере в firefox всё ок, а на телефоне, печаль-беда (((

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Сделал из вашего кода [тестовую страницу](http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-ru-516071/original.html). На моем айфоне и ноутбуке работает хорошо. Если она и на вашем телефоне выглядит как надо, то для решения проблемы нужна ссылка на вашу страницу. Или добавьте в вопрос содержимое `css/menu.css` и `css/mytable.css`.